# Sharepoint migration: Save conflict and web address issue

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I am migratin Moss 2007 site to Sharepoint 2010 without UI upgrade. I am stuck in below 2 issues.
1. I have a list named "ABC". On editform.aspx if we update the attachment and click ok it throws below error. Just for knowledge it has a event handler associated with it. But on MOSS 2007 this error does not occur even thought the event handler is asscoated to it. Kindly help.

```
 Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Save Conflict
        Your changes conflict with those made concurrently by another user. If you want your changes to be applied, click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and resubmit your changes.
```

2. How do I change the we address of the list. Please see below image. This is a feedback list in MOSS 2007. And its web address is changed to IP address (Home page). How do i do the same.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I actually cannot guess what the problem might be. Save conflicts in SharePoint generally occur when you update a database file (usually a SPListItem) twice during execution of a single thread. I even wouldn't bother mentioning links to same issues here as I know you will find bunches of them by a simple Google search. Anyway, here are a couple of clues you can start with:

1. Create a new EditForm.aspx for the list using SharePoint designer. I have seen corrupted list forms after migrating from 2007 to 2010.
2. Attach Visual Studio debugger to w3wp and debug the event receiver line by line to catch where the exception is being thrown. As I said, it is probably occurring when an item is being updated by either Update() or SystemUpdate() methods. Make sure after inserting breakpoints on your code they are not disabled. Otherwise check out the deployment process again.
3. If the above steps did not work, alternatively you can start by digging into SharePoint logs located in 14\LOGS to check where the exception is being thrown. Post a copy of the logs for me to check it out.